# Contacts not syncing on iOS 13.1

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts, ios

I have iPhone 7 plus and I have upgraded to version 13.1 but all my contacts info has disappeared.  My contacts are still on cloud, but the problem is with the sync between my device and my cloud.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are contacts accounts properly signed in and working? Do you have a backup? Are they on cloud?

Comment: Yes my contacts still on cloud, but the problem is with the sync between my device and my cloud.

Comment: That's a clue.. The way you wrote it.. seems like you permanently lost them. Logging out and in is the first step though.. Low power mode/ cellular turned off for such activities is another check to be done.. and I'd usually  wait for some time. How long have it been?

Comment: @ankii i've done everything you said and i have found a solution for it and have posted it below. thanks dear.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fix for disappearing contacts in iOS 13.1 on iPhone 7 plus:

It turns out the issue isn't with iCloud, it's with a new default in iOS 13.1.

1. Go to your Contacts app.
2. Press (+) from the top right and add new contact.
3. Save your new contact.

Now wait for ~1 minute and your contacts will appear again in your phone.

Probably the problem is in the sync functions for the first run.